# XCode 4.2 is missing the iOS5 SDK for the Simulator

Tags: xcode4, ios-simulator, ios5, failed-installation

I created an empty Single View application using Xcode 4.2 on OSX Lion 10.7.2 targeting iPhone 5. The project built happily however when launching the simulator I receive the following error message:

> iOS Simulator could not find the SDK. The SDK may need to be reinstalled.

I then tried targeting the iPad with the same results. I removed Xcode using the terminal and downloaded a fresh copy from the AppStore. The clean installation generates the exact same error.

It seems that the SDK is not being deployed during installation. Any advice or tips on how I can correctly install the iOS 5 SDK for the simulator to work?

**Update**

I downloaded the iOS 4.3 simulator which was not installed. The simulator works perfectly if I select the 4.3 SDK but for some reason is not recognizing the folder containing the 5.0 SDK.

**Update**

I reformatted the MacBook, reloaded a clean OSX Lion without restoring any backups and installed Xcode. Running the simulator directly after the installed worked, however after a reboot and relaunching Xcode the error came back. The SDK itself seems to have been corrupted. Will try and reinstall Xcode again.

Comment: Have you checked Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->Components?

Comment: @Phlibbo Yes I did. The only items showing was the 4.3 simulator which I have downloaded.

Comment: maybe if you install Xcode into another folder (e.g. /Applications/Developer) it would run. I'm having the same problem (with Asepsis) and I'm going to try this in a few minutes. If it works, I will post it as a solution.

Comment: @CarlosPreciosoDomingo I haven't tried. To be honest I don't like changing default installations unless I have no choice, however that's a personal choice. The problem was resolved for me, but I am hoping the Asepsis problem will be solved soon.

Comment: @Diago Tried and didn't work. And I can't format my mac. I'm going to contact BinaryAge.

Comment: @CarlosPreciosoDomingo They are aware of the problem, I updated my answer to reflect that. Since I use Time Machine it is fairly easy for me to rebuild my MacBook, and since I use it for development and testing I tend to do it often, which is why it doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some testing it turns out the problem is caused by a  3rd Party Software. Recently the developer of TotalFinder removed the [Asepsis](http://asepsis.binaryage.com) portion of the system and created a separate application for the handling of `DS_Store` files.

Unfortunately, this breaks the iOS Simulator once installed, and even after uninstalling Asepsis, I needed to rebuild my whole machine to get rid of the error.

**Update**

[BinaryAge](http://asepsis.binaryage.com/#known-issues) is aware of the issue with regards to Xcode 4.2 and it is now listed on the know issues page and a warning banner displayed on the download link.

**Final Update**

It seems BinaryAge has changed the way Asepsis works and this is no longer an issue with the latest versions.

Comment: finally, I got Xcode and iOS Simulator to work by stopping Asepsis and the uninstalling it.
Thanks, this question put me on the right way!

Comment: Uninstalling Asepsis worked for me as well. This problem was driving me mad!

Comment: Thank You! I can finally be productive again. Such a simple solution I would have never come to on my own.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try "File -> Reset Content and Settings ..." in the simulator ? I also encountered the similar problem, but it worked after I reset the simulator!  In fact, I also found it worked after I removed all the existing projects and created new ones, but it occurred again after I restart xcode. Fortunately the "Reset" always works for me and I hope it can be helpful for your case.

Comment: The solution I posted worked for me, and at the time it was a known problem with a third party tool. I've never had the problem since.