# My iOS Simulator is missing Safari

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

**Issue**:  Safari app missing in iOS Simulator

---

I installed Xcode 5.0a on my mini at work, and launched the iOS Simulator hoping test our mobile css.  Much to my dismay, Safari was not on the homescreen.  Rebooting the simulator did not help.  Restarting xcode, and later my mini did nothing either.  Even dragging a link (such as https://www.google.com) into the simulator would cause iOS to give an error, indicating that there was no https handler at all.  After nearly an hour of googling, I could not find *anything* about the missing Safari app. In my desparation, I was looking up everything even remotely related.

So, how do I get Safari installed on the iOS Simulator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solution**: "File -> Reset Content and Settings..." caused Safari to reappear.

---

... and then suddenly it was right there in front of me. I saw an answer by [Sihua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1728362/sihua) in [a pretty unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807719/xcode-4-2-is-missing-the-ios5-sdk-for-the-simulator) that proved to be the very thing I needed:

> *Did you try "File -> Reset Content and Settings ..." in the simulator ? [...]*

After doing this, Safari appeared in the tray as normal after the simulator rebooted.  It was back to normal. The clouds parted, the sky turned blue again, the birds started singing... the curse had been lifted!

I could get back to work.  But first, I wanted to post this solution in case there are some other poor devils out there beset by the same frustrating issue.

Comment: in my case not working even i did reset content and settings… i unable to see safari in my simulator…

Comment: Didn't work for me for iOS 7.1 with XCode 5.1. But interestingly, Safari showed up when switch to iOS 6.1. What's up with the later iOS versions?